# Calculate pairwise difference from specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe, pandas

I have the following dataframe where I show how many times I have seen a move from Item1 to Item 2. For example there is one transition from A to B, 2 from A to C , 1 from C to A

---

```
    Item1   Item2   Moves
  1  A       B       1
  2  A       C       2
  3  B       D       3
  4  C       A       1
  5  C       B       5
  6  D       B       4
  7  D       C       1
```

---

I would like to calculate the difference between two items, so a newly constructed Dataframe would be the following

```
    Item1   Item2   Moves
  1  A       B       1
  2  A       C       1
  3  B       D      -1
  4  C       B       5
  5  D       C       1
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do that using Pandas? I guess i need to index on the first two columns but I quite new in Pandas and i face a lot of difficulties.
Thanks

EDIT 
There can't be any duplicate pairs.For example you cant see twice a->b (but you can of course see b->a)

Comment: Is it important to you that the transition direction first seen is preserved, or would a row with `B C -5` be acceptable?

Comment: It is not that important, but I guess that its a matter of preference of either deleting the first encounter of the two transitions or the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure someone could simplify this down to fewer lines, but I've left it long to help clarify what is going on.  In a nutshell, split the dataframe into two pieces based on whether 'Item1' is earlier in the alphabet than 'Item2'.  Then flip 'Item1' and 'Item2' and negate 'Moves' for one piece.  Glue them back together and use the `groupby` function to aggregate the rows.

```
>>> df
  Item1 Item2  Moves
0     A     B      1
1     A     C      2
2     B     D      3
3     C     A      1
4     C     B      5
5     D     B      4
6     D     C      1
>>> swapidx = df['Item1'] < df['Item2']
>>> df1 = df[swapidx]
>>> df2 = df[swapidx^True]
>>> df1
  Item1 Item2  Moves
0     A     B      1
1     A     C      2
2     B     D      3
>>> df2
  Item1 Item2  Moves
3     C     A      1
4     C     B      5
5     D     B      4
6     D     C      1
>>> df2[['Item1', 'Item2']] = df2[['Item2', 'Item1']]
>>> df2['Moves'] = df2['Moves']*-1
>>> df2
  Item1 Item2  Moves
3     A     C     -1
4     B     C     -5
5     B     D     -4
6     C     D     -1
>>> df3 = df1.append(df2)
>>> df3.groupby(['Item1', 'Item2'], as_index=False).sum()
  Item1 Item2  Moves
0     A     B      1
1     A     C      1
2     B     C     -5
3     B     D     -1
4     C     D     -1
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer seems quite elegant to me- I had managed to do this using lists but I was looping through the dictionary for every pair to find the opposite pair, which is quite inefficient

Comment: Your suggested edit was a good one.  I'm not sure why it got rejected by others, but I was unable to 'approve' it after it had been rejected by 3 people.  I've made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

First create a row which just contains the string for Item1 and Item2.

```
In [11]: df['Items'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Item1'] + row['Item2'], axis=1)

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
  Item1 Item2  Moves Items
1     A     B      1    AB
2     A     C      2    AC
3     B     D      3    BD
4     C     A      1    CA
5     C     B      5    CB
6     D     B      4    DB
7     D     C      1    DC
```

and if `Items` is in (alphabetical) order leave it, else switch it and negate `Moves`:

```
In [13]: df[['Items','Moves']] = df.apply(lambda row: (row[['Items', 'Moves']])
                                                       if row['Items'][0] <= row['Items'][1]
                                                       else (row['Items'][::-1], -row['Moves']),
                                          axis=1)

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  Item1 Item2  Moves Items
1     A     B      1    AB
2     A     C      2    AC
3     B     D      3    BD
4     C     A     -1    AC
5     C     B     -5    BC
6     D     B     -4    BD
7     D     C     -1    CD

In [15]: g = df.groupby('Items')

In [16]: g.sum()
Out[16]: 
       Moves
Items       
AB         1
AC         1
BC        -5
BD        -1
CD        -1
```

Which is most of the way, and may be enough for you.

To get the desired final output a hackey way could be:

```
In [17]: df1 = g.first() # the first row in each group

In [18]: df1.Moves = g.sum()

In [19]: df2 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

In [20]: df2
Out[20]: 
  Item1 Item2  Moves
0     A     B      1
1     A     C      1
2     C     B     -5
3     B     D     -1
4     D     C     -1
```

However, notice the negation isn't quite right (for those the wrong way around e.g. DC rather than CD):

```
In [21]: df2.Moves = df2.apply(lambda row: row['Moves']
                                            if row['Item1'] <= row['Item2']
                                            else -row['Moves'],
                                axis=1)

In [22]: df2
Out[22]: 
  Item1 Item2  Moves
0     A     B      1
1     A     C      1
2     C     B      5
3     B     D     -1
4     D     C      1
```